# Javascript - get undefined when trying to get value of element that clearly stated in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make simple html with javascript for studying html. But when I run the html in browser, it return undefined in console log when trying to get Button 1 and Button 2 value.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="js/Try.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Try</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <a type="button" id="Button1" href="#" value="B1" onmouseover="PutValueLog(this)">Button 1</a>
            <a type="button" id="Button2" href="#" value="B2" onmouseover="PutValueLog(this)">Button 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var tempval;

function PutValueLog(button){
    tempval = button.value;
    console.log(button);
    console.log(tempval);
}
```

And the console log that I get:

[image: log image]

Can anyone tell me why that happen? What I must do to get value not undefined but B1 or B2 in my console log?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `a` tag and not a `input`. So you cannot use the `value` to get the value of the anchor tag. Use the `.getAttribute()` function to get the value of the attribute.

```js
var tempval;

function PutValueLog(button){
  debugger;
    tempval = button.getAttribute('value');
    //console.log(button);
    alert(tempval);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <a type="button" id="Button1" href="#" value="B1" onmouseover="PutValueLog(this)">Button 1</a>
            <a type="button" id="Button2" href="#" value="B2" onmouseover="PutValueLog(this)">Button 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as following:

```
var tempval;

function PutValueLog(button){
    tempval = button.getAttribute("value"); //value is not a defined property of an anchor
    console.log(button);
    console.log(tempval);
}
```